# Upload image with ajax, HttpPostedFileBase is null Mvc Asp

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I must upload image before Form is submitted. So I used ajax to do it.

Here is my HelpController:

```
[HttpPost]
public void AcceptUpload(HttpPostedFileBase TemporaryForLast, string ReferanceNo)
{
    TemporaryForLast.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Profiles/images/" + ReferanceNo + "/") + "HoldCopy" + ".jpg");
}
```

Here is my view:

```
<input id="HoldCopy" type="file" name="HoldCopy" accept="image/*">
```

Ans Script:

```
$("#acceptUpload").click(function () {
    var formData= new FormData();
    var imagefile=document.getElementById("HoldCopy").files[0];
    formData.append("imageFile",imageFile);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "/Help/AcceptUpload", true);
    xhr.addEventListener("load", function (evt) { UploadComplete(evt); }, false);
    xhr.addEventListener("error", function (evt) { UploadFailed(evt); }, false);
    xhr.send(formData);
});
```

`error` functions are also updated.

Comment: Ajax don't support file upload. No one told you that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

View

Instead of Jquery Ajax you could use

```
<script>
            function SubmitButtonOnclick()
            { 
                var formData= new FormData();
                var imagefile=document.getElementById("imageFile").files[0];
                formData.append("imageFile",imageFile);
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open("POST", "/Help/AcceptUpload", true);
                xhr.addEventListener("load", function (evt) { UploadComplete(evt); }, false);
                xhr.addEventListener("error", function (evt) { UploadFailed(evt); }, false);
                xhr.send(formData);

            }

      function UploadComplete(evt) {
        if (evt.target.status == 200) 
                alert("Logo uploaded successfully.");

        else 
                 alert("Error Uploading File");
        }

    function UploadFailed(evt) {
        alert("There was an error attempting to upload the file.");

    }
 </script>
```

Comment: it gives an error ReferenceError: imageFile is not defined
 

formData.append("imageFile", imageFile);

Comment: @BarsDS according to your code this line will change `var imagefile=document.getElementById("HoldCopy").files[0];`

Comment: yes i have changed it, and this error appeared after i changed

Comment: can you update the code what you have done

Comment: it's very strange, but i resolve the problem by renaming imageFile to ImageFile. anyway i solve the problem with your help. thanks a lot Nilesh

Comment: ohh...its strange...anyways glad it helped you